# No placeholders in format string

Tags: go

This question is about best practices when formatting strings in Go.

Whenever I'm using the print library like so:

`log.Printf("Greeting:",resp.GetMessage())`

I get a warning from my IDE (Goland) saying:

`No placeholders in format string`

What does that mean? What would a proper print look like?

Comment: It means you forgot the `%s`.

Comment: It is not specifically about log structure, but string formatting as you use `Print**f**`. So, did you try `log.Printf("Greeting:%s\n",resp.GetMessage())`?

Comment: @vahdet you never need a trailing `\n` in `log` calls, just so you know.

Comment: It was a fair question, I tried to specify it as much as possible and followed all of the patterns, and yet you guys downvoted and got me banned, thanks for that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`log.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Printf) expects a format string as its first argument:

```
func Printf(format string, v ...interface{})
```

A format string is a string where you may use *verbs* with modifiers to lay out how you want the result string to look like. A format string without any verbs is likely an error (indicating you probably forgot something from it, or if it truly does not need verbs, you shouldn't use `Pritnf()` which expects a format string). You can read more about format strings and their Go syntax at the doc of the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package.

For example, this is a format string:

```
"Greeting: %s"
```

This is how it would be used:

```
log.Printf("Greeting: %s", resp.GetMessage())
```

This is a very simple example and does not warrant formatted output. If you don't have a format string, use [`log.Print()`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Print) or [`log.Println()`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Println) instead (they don't require a format string):

```
log.Println("Greeting:", resp.GetMessage())
```

The `Printf()` variant comes handy when you need more complex formatting, not just log 2 strings (concatenated).

For example:

```
log.Printf("Hi, my name is %s, and I'm %d years old.", "Bob", 22)
```

Output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/R3WxT5MT_b3)):

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Hi, my name is Bob, and I'm 22 years old.
```