# What does "printf-style function with dynamic format string and no further arguments should use print-style function instead" mean?

Tags: go

> printf-style function with dynamic format string and no further arguments should use print-style function instead

My VScode keeps highlighting my `fmt.Fprintf(w, prettyJSON.String())` statements with the warning stated above. Not sure what it means, or how to fix. Here is an example on how I use `Fprintf()`:

```golang
func (s *Server) getWorkSpaces(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    client := &http.Client{}
    var prettyJSON bytes.Buffer
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "url.com", nil)
    if err != nil {
        // if there was an error parsing the request, return an error to user and quit function
        responses.ERROR(w, http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Errorf("unable to read request body: %v", err))
        return
    }


    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        // if there was an error parsing the request, return an error to user and quit function
        responses.ERROR(w, http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Errorf("unable to read request body: %v", err))
        return
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    error := json.Indent(&prettyJSON, body, "", "\t")
    if error != nil {
        log.Println("JSON parse error: ", error)
        return
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(w, prettyJSON.String())
}
```

How can I stop this error? Could someone explain to me why my VScode is throwing that up on the screen? Note that my code runs and works well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`fmt.Fprintf()`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Fprintf) expects a format string that may contain verbs that will be substituted with arguments. If you do not pass arguments, that hints you're likely not having / using a format string, so you shouldn't use `fmt.Fprintf()` in the first place.

To just write arguments into an `io.Writer`, use [`fmt.Fprint()`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Fprint).

```
fmt.Fprint(w, prettyJSON.String())
```

The warning is more than justified from vet, because the format string may not get outputted as-is:

```
fmt.Print("%%\n")
fmt.Printf("%%\n")
```

The above prints (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Juy-0jWo0ug)):

```
%%
%
```

The `%` is a special character in format strings, and to emit (output) a single `%` sign you have to use double `%` in the format string. This is just to prove the point, there are other differences.

See related questions:

[No placeholders in format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076692/no-placeholders-in-format-string/58076735#58076735)

[Format a Go string without printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/format-a-go-string-without-printing/31742265#31742265)

Comment: thank you for your response. Now I understand!

Comment: This is a question that is better answered for a case-by-case basis, but when given the chance, which one is better to use? `Fprintf` with arguments, or a simple `Fprint`?

Comment: `Fprintf()` can be used to generate formatted output easily. `Fprint` is to just write arguments. E.g. `Fprintf(w, "Bob is %d years old", 12)` will output `Bob is 12 years old`.

Comment: See [Format a Go string without printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123865/format-a-go-string-without-printing/31742265#31742265) for details.